How to draw Gizmos in Scene View when a ScriptableObject file is selected?
I want to be able to visualize where my 'ResourceAreas' are whilst in edit mode so i tried to create a tool to display them in the scene view. Here is the code for the editor:
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

[CustomEditor(typeof(ResourceAreas))]
public class ResourceAreasEditor : Editor
{
    void OnSceneGUI()
    {
        ResourceAreas resourceAreas = (ResourceAreas)target;

        foreach (ResourceArea area in resourceAreas.resourceAreas)
        {
            Handles.color = Color.red;
            Handles.DrawWireDisc(area.center, new Vector3(0,1,0), area.radius);

            EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
            Vector3 newCenter = Handles.PositionHandle(area.center, Quaternion.identity);
            if (EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck())
            {
                Undo.RecordObject(resourceAreas, "Move Resource Area Center");
                area.center = newCenter;
                EditorUtility.SetDirty(resourceAreas);
            }
        }
    }
}

However upon selecting my ResourceAreas scriptable object no gizmos appear in the scene view. This is the code for the scriptable object and what one looks like in inspector:
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class ResourceArea
{
    public string resourceName;
    public Vector3 center;  // Center point in terrain space
    public float radius;    // Radius of the resource area
    public int resourceCount;
}

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "ResourceAreas", menuName = "ScriptableObjects/ResourceAreas", order = 1)]
public class ResourceAreas : ScriptableObject
{
    public ResourceArea[] resourceAreas;
}



You need to create an Editor Window Script. This script will create a custom editor window that listens to selection changes and draws Gizmos in the Scene view.
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class ResourceAreasEditorWindow : EditorWindow
{
   private ResourceAreas resourceAreas;

   [MenuItem("Window/Resource Areas Editor")]
   public static void ShowWindow()
   {
       GetWindow<ResourceAreasEditorWindow>("Resource Areas Editor");
   }

   private void OnEnable()
   {
       Selection.selectionChanged += OnSelectionChanged;
       SceneView.duringSceneGui += OnSceneGUI;
   }

   private void OnDisable()
   {
       Selection.selectionChanged -= OnSelectionChanged;
       SceneView.duringSceneGui -= OnSceneGUI;
   }

   private void OnSelectionChanged()
   {
       if (Selection.activeObject is ResourceAreas)
       {
        resourceAreas = Selection.activeObject as ResourceAreas;
       }
   }

   private void OnSceneGUI(SceneView sceneView)
   {
       if(resourceAreas == null)
         return;

       foreach (ResourceArea area in resourceAreas.resourceAreas)
       {
           Handles.color = Color.red;
           Handles.DrawWireDisc(area.center, new Vector3(0,1,0), area.radius);
           SceneView.RepaintAll();
       }
   }

   private void OnGUI()
   {
       EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Selected ResourceAreas:", EditorStyles.boldLabel);
       if (resourceAreas != null)
       {
           EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Name: ", resourceAreas.name);
           // Display other properties of resourceAreas if needed
       }
       else
           EditorGUILayout.LabelField("No ResourceAreas selected.");
 
   }
 }

Then, open the custom editor window via Window > Resource Areas Editor. Select a ResourceAreas ScriptableObject in the Project window. it will draw wiredisc in the Scene view when a ResourceAreas ScriptableObject is selected.


fyi, i've just updated the answer for better solution.
